# Removing Range of <option>s Inside Group of <select>s

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a jQuery set of select items and I'm trying to remove a range of options from inside them.  I want to use variables but can't figure it out.

```
servoSelects.find('option')
//want to remove all options starting at index 1 and ending at variable
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have any html like following:

```
<select id="select_item" class="form-control">
<option value="">Select</option>
<option value="Option1">Option1</option>
<option value="Option2">Option2</option>
<option value="Option3">Option3</option>
<option value="Option4">Option4</option>
</select>
```

and you want to remove any options using jquery you can use the following code

```
var val = "Option3";
$("#select_item:visible option[value='"+val+"']").remove();
```

The above code will remove option3.

Comment: It doesn't allow for a range of options to be removed so it doesn't really help.

Comment: servoSelects.filter('.lgServo').find('option:lt(3)').not('option:lt(1)').remove();
This doesn't allow for me to use a variable (as far as I know).  Another problem it has is it keeps the first option for the first select but deletes the first option for every select after the first on the Web page.

Answer (score 0):

```
servoSelects.filter('.lgServo').each(function() {
        $(this).find('option').slice(1, lowValue).remove();
});
```

This code takes the jQuery set (the select elements), grabs only the ones with class "lgServo" and uses slice().remove() to let me remove a range of options with one or 2 variables.